# A cell complex constructed from singular knots

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, cw-complexes, finite-type-invariants

Let $\mathcal K_n$ be the set of all $n$-singular knots up to isotopy,i.e. an immersion of $S^1$ into $\mathbb R^3$ with $n$ transverse double points that is an embedding when restricted to the complement of the preimages of these double points. Let $\mathcal C_n$ be its linear span. We can construct a cell complex as follows. Let $\mathcal K_0$ be vertices, and $\mathcal K_1$ be edges, we attach vertices of $K\in \mathcal K_1$ to the two knots obtained by resolving its double point, we also have a map $r:\mathcal C_1\to \mathcal C_{0},K\mapsto K_+-K_-$. Continuing this, we can view $\mathcal K_n$ as $n$-cubes and attatch its $2n$ faces to the $(n-1)$-singular knots obtained by resolving its $n$ double points in $\mathcal K_{n-1}$, and we also have a 'resolving map' $r: \mathcal C_{n} \to \mathcal C_{n-1},K\mapsto \frac1{n}\sum_i K_+^i-K_-^i$ where $K_+^i,K_-^i$ is obtained be resolving its $i$-th double points. Finally we obtain an infinite cell complex $\mathcal C=\bigcup_n \mathcal C_{n}$ and maps $r: \mathcal  C_n\to \mathcal C_{n-1}$.

I'm learning finite type invariants and came up with this construction. If we consider the dual map $r^*:C_n^*\to C_{n+1}^*$, then finite type invariants are just those functionals  $f\in C_0^*$ satisfying $(r^*)^{n+1}f=0$.

My questions are:

1. Is this construction reasonable?
2. What can we say about the topology of $\mathcal C$(i.e. is there a good way to compute its homology/homotopy groups)?
3. How is the theory of finite type invariants related to this complex with maps $r$?

Please kindly correct me if I said anything wrong or stupid! Any reference or comment is welcome!

Comment: It would help if you say what an $n$-singular knot is.  There might be further difficulties -- it's best to assume readers have no experience with this terminology.